# android.annotation cannot be imported : all annotation cannot be resolved

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have some problems occur on my project which is :

1. android.annotation cannot be resolved.

For your information, I have migrated to androidx library. I assume that all my codes will be automatically change to androidx but only some of them changed. Current Version Android Studio is 3.5.

What have I done are

1. Invalidate and Restart
2. Clean and Rebuild
3. All path for sdk has been selected

The application installed on my devices, but keep stopping. Here are my details:

**build.gradle(project)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        //classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
        //classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()


    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle(module app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kartik.barcode"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.palette:palette:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.media:media:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.0.2@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.1.0'//for firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    //annotationProcessor 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'


}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**HERE THE PROBLEMS OCCUR**
[logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yk3JT.png)

When I view the java class, the import still android and not androidx. Even I changed to androidx, it still cannot be resolved.
[java class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlIeL.png)

Comment: The logcat you've provided says the crash is because of a NullpointerException, are you sure it's related to the annotations?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this

```
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
```

and delete yours imports once and reImport

like this

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
```

Comment: after I remove the line, and remove the import. I need to write the same import or import androidx.annotation ?

Comment: NO just import it from default android package

Comment: Thankyou for your explanation. but how to import from default pakage on android studio 3.5

Comment: It will show you for import suggestions when you click on that particular annotation.